# MRTK Not Recognizing Handtracking Input

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am currently using Unity with Microsoft's Mixed Reality Toolkit to create a simple game that places a square that can be moved using hand gesture's (air-tapped and dragged). So far I have attached the ManipulationHandler and NearInterationGrabbable to the square game object such as in the tutorial: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch4).

When running the Unity project in the Unity player, the square is able to be manipulated with the GGVPointer. However, when I deploy the Hololens, no gesture input is recognized.

[Here is my object hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnHpy.png)

[and the contents of the cube under inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ6ts.png)

Current Development Evironment:

- MRTK 2.2 & 2.3
- 2019.3.0f6 & .9f1
- Deployment on:

  - Hololens 1
  - Hololens 1 and 2 emulator

In regards to the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502650/why-is-air-tap-gesture-not-working-on-hololens1-in-my-unity-mrtk-app), after attaching the script in the answer and debugging it in the Hololens emulator I receive the error :

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF80850A839 (KernelBase.dll) in Hololens Test Project.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x000000008000000B, 0x0000000080070490, 0x0000000000000014, 0x000000506E7FDA50).
```

Comment: As a test, could you re-add Mixed Reality Toolkit to your scene and configure: 1. Detele MixedRealityPlayspace and MixedRealityToolkit object in the Hierarchy window. 2. From the menu bar, select Mixed Reality Toolkit -> Add to Scene and Configure. Then build and run your project on the HoloLens. Do you see the same behavior?  There should be only one child object camera Main Camera under the mixed reality game space. Besides, If you are using Unity 2019.3, the MRTK 2.3 release will work in that environment without issue.

Comment: Thanks Hernando, I removed the MRTK from my project via the Hierarchy window and re-added it through the Mixed Reality toolkit menu. By following these steps exclusively, the Tracked Pose Driver is not added to the main camera. This causes the application to fix the headsets view to a static camera and does not allow for positional tracking within the game environment. Could it be a setting that I am missing within the MRTK input configuration?

Comment: Tracked Pose Driver is not a necessary component for the main camera, and it should not cause the issue that freeze headphone view. Could you reproduce this issue in the examples provided by MRTK? The main cameras in these samples have also not added Tracked Pose Driver, but they should work well in HoloLens.

Comment: After deploying an example scene to the Hololens 1 and Hololens 2 device, the 'freezing' headset view issue if not reproduced. However, gestures are still not recognized. The gaze cursor does not enlarge when the hand is in view as well.

Comment: The examples from MRTK  should be able to work well. I followed your steps and try to reproduce this issue but failed. The cause of this issue may in your unity project settings. Please follow this step-by-step guidance to troubleshoot your Unity Project Settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/configure-unity-project#per-project-settings . Or create another new unity project and get start with this document: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - after you want to change something on the MixedRealityToolkit by copying/cloning the profiles some options like "Input System" gets disabled - so you just have to reactivate it again:

[image]